# Android Studio Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, syntax-error

In Android Studio when i want to add retrofit dependencies and gson converter then gradle build.kt are providing error. Error like this Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5IJP.png)

I try to solve the error which provide by android studio and i expect to sync gradle bulid [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTmje.png)

Comment: use same (" ") when using implementation

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin DSL for Gradle, the syntax for implementing dependencies is slightly different from Groovy. Here's how you can implement the mentioned libraries using Kotlin syntax:

```
implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0")
implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0")
```

When implementing other dependencies, make sure to follow the same pattern:

```
implementation("your.library.group:your-library-artifact:your-library-version")
```

For more information, you can refer to the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/build/migrate-to-kotlin-dsl#:%7E:text=Kotlin%20is%20preferred%20over%20the,time%20checking%20and%20IDE%20support.)